# Prevent UDF from being called on vba Excel Sheet Deletion/Addition

Tags: excel

Before Deletion and Creation of Worksheets using

```
Sheets(xxx).Delete
```

or

```
Worksheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets(xxx)).Name = xxxxxx
```

User Defined Functions(UDF) are being called.

Is there a way to prevent UDF being called. I just want to create or delete a sheet

Comment: Have you tried changing your macro security settings? If you disable macros in this workbook, these event macros should not be called.  Otherwise, it would probably be best to review the event macros and modify them, as needed, to allow your desired performance.

Answer (score 1):

When Excel is in Automatic calculation mode deleting a worksheet triggers a recalculation.
If your UDFs are Volatile or downstream dependent on a volatile function or a cell on the deleted worksheet they will be recalculated.
See http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm for more information on volatile functions and actions that trigger a recalculation.